# what used after ''had great motivation''?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> She had great motivation ... the exam.

a)in passing
b)passing
c)to pass
which answer is true? and why?

Comment: What do you think yourself?

Comment: i know the answer, this is a test given with answer. the answer is ,,to pass''. i want to know why it is. i thought there is any rule using infinitive after expressions ,,have great'' or ,,had great''. i searched about those expression in google for half an hour. but i didn't find anything about those. i found special expression about using gerund. i think my question is very simple to you and others because of there is no answer.

Comment: @cardinal do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know I would say "She had **a** great motivation to pass the exam"

Comment: The other two may also be grammatical construction like He had a great motivation in what he's doing or something like this. I am learner though. But to+ infinitive are can be used to modify different things and you are right about it here.